# Pass variable with Invoke-SSHCommand in Powershell

Tags: powershell, windows-10

I have a PowerShell script that attempts to invoke bash shell script on a remote Linux machine. I use -ArgumentList to pass a parameter but get an error.

Sample om my script:

```
 param ( [Parameter(mandatory=true)[string]$param1 )
 
 Remove-SshSession 
 $session = New-SshSession -ComputerName $myServer -Command $StopServer
 
 $result = Invoke-SshCommand -ComputerName $myServer -ScriptBlock {/root/scripts/Test.sh $args[0]} -ArgumentList $param1
```

The error:

```
    Invoke-SshCommand : A Parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'ArgumentList'. At C:\TestProject\InstallBuild.ps1:6 
+ ... root/test.sh $args[0]} -ArgumentList $param1...
+ 
  + CategogyInnfo       : InvalidArgument: (:) [Invoke-SshCommand], ParameterBindingException
  + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Invoke-SshCommand
```

How do I pass an argument to -ScriptBlock with Invoke-SshCommand?

Comment: Go to https://github.com/darkoperator/Posh-SSH/blob/master/docs/Invoke-SSHCommand.md and read about the Syntax as well as Examples.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon I read posh-ssh docs previously. There is nothing written about passing an argument to the script. The script, I try to invoke remotely, accepts a parameter and I need to pass a value for it in my PowerShell script shown above.

Comment: Just put in variable in the `[-Command]` parameter along with the command you want to execute on the Linux host. If you want to pass an object you will need to serialize it first.